# ETCD kubeadm getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, etcd, kubeadm

I would like to use the etcdctl functionnalities of my etcd pod from my kurnetes cluster but I can't. I have install my kubernetes from kubeadm and I have 1 master and 1 node.

When I try commands etcdctl from inside of my etcd pod, I get those errors:

> client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured;
>   error #0:malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02" ;
>   error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: getsockopt: connection refused

But when I check my etcd pod log, it seems healthy :

[image]

Comment: Did you expose your ETCD from kubernetes? because it is inside the cluster and it may not listen to port 4001 on localhost.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379
>   --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key member list

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have `etcd` listening for client connections on `https://127.0.0.1:2379` and you have client certificate authentication enabled as far as i can see. You should then be able to run the following command to connect to `etcd`:

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl member list \
  --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
  --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
  --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
```

Basically `etcd` expects you to authenticate using a client certificate.

Also, since you're running version 3.x of `etcd` you have to tell `etcdctl` that by providing the `ETCDCTL_API` environment variable.

**EDIT:**

For reference:

I was using `kubeadm` version 1.11.1 which installed version 3.2.18 of `etcd` on a server running Ubuntu 18.04 when testing the command above.

Comment: it seems better but still a problem i have this error message :

`warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated
Error:  grpc: timed out when dialing`

Comment: @Yummel Good that you got one step forward at least! This could be a TLS authentication problem.. maybe i was wrong using the certificate i used in my answer. AFAIK `kubeadm` generates the certificates with the correct SANs (Subject Alternate Names) and `127.0.0.1` are included there. Check the SANs with: `openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt -text -noout`, look for them in the x509v2 Extensions part. In the manifest file (yaml) that `kubeadm` generates for etcd there's a liveness probe configured, test with that `etcdctl` command once. The certificate used there might work.

Comment: @Yummel I tried to reproduce your error without success using a Ubuntu 18.04 master node initialized with `kubeadm init`, just so i could get access to a `etcd` container. Everything works fine for me on `etcd` version 3.2.18, they bumped the default version of `etcd` in `kubeadm` from 3.1.12 to 3.2.18 around 5 months ago, maybe it works better if you upgrade `kubeadm` to the latest version (i got 1.11.1) and re-run your cluster. Also, that warning about `ServerName` is gone in the latest version of `etcd`, as i understand it they removed it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer ! i have check for the SANs it's `localhost` but i only have `v3` version not `v2`. Then i have check in the manisfest and try to run the same command without success

Comment: `/ # ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernet
es/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key get foo
2018-08-03 09:13:16.006137 I | warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated`

Comment: `/ # ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernet
es/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key get foo
2018-08-03 09:13:35.766156 I | warning: ignoring ServerName for user-provided CA for backwards compatibility is deprecated`

Comment: @Yummel Looks OK i think, and if you issue that `etcdctl` command with `member list` instead of `get foo` then you'll see a list of your `etcd` cluster member(s) right? In `etcd` 3.2.18 the command in my answer works flawlessly using the server.key and server.crt files for authentication but for you it ends up in that `timed out when dialing` error.

Comment: I try to upgrade my cluster and it fail too because of etcd

Comment: `[upgrade/etcd] Failed to upgrade etcd: couldn't upgrade control plane. kubeadm has tried to recover everything into the earlier state. Errors faced: [timed out waiting for the condition]
[upgrade/etcd] Waiting for previous etcd to become available
[util/etcd] Waiting 0s for initial delay
[util/etcd] Attempting to see if all cluster endpoints are available 1/10
[upgrade/etcd] Etcd was rolled back and is now available`

Comment: I'm not sure how your environment looks like, is this cluster used for testing purposes or do you use it in production? `kubeadm` versions follows the `kubernetes` releases, if you don't mind then you could tear it down and re-initialize it with a newer version of all binaries needed for running `kubeadm`. I guess you've seen the following section in the guide for installing `kubeadm`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/#installing-kubeadm-kubelet-and-kubectl. I've never upgraded only `etcd` with `kubeadm`, i suspect it's possible though.

Comment: Thanks it works ! but if i want to explore kubernetes data which command i should use ?

Comment: Great! I would recommend you to look at that data through the API server. But with `etcdctl` you could do something like `get "" --prefix=true`. Please this link for more info on how to access the cluster API: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/, i'll update my answer with the version of `etcd` i was testing the original command with. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if you feel like you got one :)